# BufferedWriter closed throws exception

Tags: java, android, exception, bufferedwriter

I have made a method to write a log in an external storage of Android.

```
    public int writeLog(String clase, String metodo, Object object){
    try{
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Constants.ROUTE_FILES_TEXT);
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(folder.toString() + "/log.txt", true);

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        out.write("Hora: " + TimeService.getCurrentTimeStamp(Constants.TIMESTAMP_PATTERN) + "\n");
        out.write("Clase: " + clase + "\n");
        out.write("Método: " + metodo + "\n");
        out.write("Mensaje: " + object + "\n\n\n");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.d(TAG, ex.toString());
        return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine, but the method throws an exception always. The exception is:

```
06-13 01:00:02.043: D/FileService(14439): java.io.IOException: OutputStreamWriter is closed
```

But, If I comment  the close of the BufferedWriter then the method works fine and I haven't got any exception in my code.

```
    public int writeLog(String clase, String metodo, Object object){
    try{
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Constants.ROUTE_FILES_TEXT);
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(folder.toString() + "/log.txt", true);

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        out.write("Hora: " + TimeService.getCurrentTimeStamp(Constants.TIMESTAMP_PATTERN) + "\n");
        out.write("Clase: " + clase + "\n");
        out.write("Método: " + metodo + "\n");
        out.write("Mensaje: " + object + "\n\n\n");
        out.flush();
        //out.close();
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.d(TAG, ex.toString());
        return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is that right? Why?

Comment: Exceptions are thrown, not returned. Commenting out the close is what fixed it, not the flush. And flush before close is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing `out` causes all underlying streams and writers to be closed as well, so the calls to:

```
fw.flush();
fw.close();
```

are redundant after `out.close()` has been called because at that point `fw` is already closed.

This leads to the second problem, which is calling `fw.flush()` when `fw` is already closed... calling 'flush()' on a stream or writer that has already been closed usually causes an exception like the one you're seeing.

I suggest that you don't close `fw` manually and instead use `out.close()` to close the whole output chain.

Comment: I have commented fw.flush() and fw.close() and it works fine everything!!! My method create the file and write correctly in it!!! Thanks @Mike Laren!!!